# Need help to run an if statement inside an object to change that objects attributes (JAVA)

Tags: java, object

Im not extremely high level at this and this is my first time really working with objects and classes. I am trying to make a card game and want to color the card's suit name either red or black with the Java color code things. Each card is its own object, with a suit and a number value. Heres the "Card" class:

```
        public class Card {
String suit = Main.generateCardSuit();
int value = Main.generateCardValue();

**if(suit.equals("Spades") || suit.equals("Clubs")){
    String cardColor = Colors.WHITE;
} else {
    String cardColor = Colors.RED;
}**

String cardDisplay = value + ", "+ cardColor + suit + Colors.RESET;}
```

the methods in the Main class that determine the suit and values:

```
` public static String generateCardSuit() {
        String cardSuit = "0";
        int suitDeterminer = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
        switch (suitDeterminer) {
            case 1:
                cardSuit = "Spades";
                break;
            case 2:
                cardSuit = "Clubs";
                break;
            case 3:
                cardSuit = "Hearts";
                break;
            case 4:
                cardSuit = "Diamonds";
                break;
        }
        return cardSuit;
    }

    public static int generateCardValue() {
        int gameValue = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 13+1);
        return gameValue;
    }`
```

How the Card class is used:

```
   public static void printUserHand(ArrayList < Card > userHand) {
    for (int i = 0; i < userHand.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ": " + userHand.get(i).cardDisplay);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList < Card > userHand = new ArrayList < Card > ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        userHand.add(new Card());
    }
    for (int i = 7; i > 0; i--) {
        Card gameCard = new Card();
        System.out.println("The dealer turns up a: " + gameCard.cardDisplay + "\n");
```

...

So i need each cards color to be an attribute, but the bolded IF statement I have in the object doesnt work. Based on how my code is working, I dont know of a way that it could go in the Main class without causing a lot of other problems.

Comment: Despite some other problems with your code the most basic one is that there is no usage of your card class in the program being executed at all.

Comment: You should add the if statement inside a constructor and if you don't know what is the constructor read this https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_constructors.asp

Comment: @JorgeCampos This is by no means all of my code, it is just the most relevant pieces I thought to share. I can paste all of it but that would be a lot.

Comment: Well without seeing how the two pieces fit together one can only assume what I already mentioned. At least that should be on your post.

Comment: @Abdulmuhaymin Would the constructor go in my Main class? or would it go in the Card class itself. Also, there are multiple objects being created by the class Card, and the suit is dependent on each objects .suit attribute. Can I take a classes attribute as an argument for its own constructor?

Comment: @JorgeCampos added more information, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Card` class has a severe problem: it is not a class at all, it tries to execute code outside a method.

Give it a private field called `cardDisplay` and initialize it in a constructor of `Card`. Add a method to retrieve the value of cardDisplay:

```java
private final String cardDisplay;

public Card() {
  // put all the code from your version of Card here
  this.cardDisplay = cardDisplay;
}

public String getCardDisplay() {
  return cardDisplay;
}
```

If you skip the declaration in your code (that's where you specify the type of the local variable), you can even save a line with

```java
  cardDisplay = value + ", "+ cardColor + suit + Colors.RESET;
```

Just don't skip the declaration for real local variables that are not available as fields, like probably `cardColor`.

Comment: but i specifically need to utilize all of the attributes, not just cardDisplay. In a past iteration of this project, I had all of these in the same Main class and it didnt allow me to do anything more without drastically increasing the amount of code needed.

Comment: As you updated your question, I did the update for my answer ;)

Comment: if you don't know what `final` is for, you can leave it out. It basically says that you can only assign a value once, and for a field you have to do that before the constructor has finished.
Also with your level of experience you should not access fields of a class directly from outside. This is against object oriented programming, think of it as "reserved" for special use cases.

Comment: You can add `suit` and `value` in a similar way, just add fields for them like I did for `cardDisplay` in my example, add getter-methods for them and initialize the fields inside the constructor.

Comment: Im still struggling with the concept of a constructor. Do i put that code in Main.java or Card.java? and i need each card to generate with its own set of value and suit, would this change that? Im sorry im not getting it, my brain is mush from all of this.

Comment: The constructor I put in my example is `Card()` so it is a constructor for the `Card` class - has to go into Card.java.

The constructor is called on each call of `new Card()`, and from there it generates a new suit and value. It does this by calling the methods in `Main` - but you could easily move those methods to the `Card` class, then they won't have to be `static` anymore - and you have to adjust their calls by removing that `Main.` specification from the call. Test the code to find out if you get all the same card over and over again, or individual ones ;)

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far, but can I actually use the "if/else" in the constructor or will that continue the issue of not compiling? Again, thanks, your explanation really helped.

Comment: Yes, where I put my `// put all the code from your version of Card here` you should literally copy everything that is inside the outermost `{}` of your Card-class. The constructor is kind of a special method that ensures that the object that is created from that class (think of the class as a blueprint) is properly initialized and can be used in your code.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the Java Tutorial from Oracle (originally Sun) about the very basics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html. I don't know if you just learn Java in some institution, but you seem to lack some really important basics, what is a class, what is an object, etc. Go through that lesson "Classes and Object" for now, this should give you some insights.

Answer (score 0):

There is a data type named Color, you might want to try setting `Color cardColor = Color.yourColor` and then using this value directly as your color with cardColor.

EDIT to include solution:

```
if(suit.equals("Spades") || suit.equals("Clubs")){
    Color cardColor = Colors.WHITE;
} else {
    Color cardColor = Colors.RED;
}
```

You might want to give this list a look, lot of other ressources there if you are starting out:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html

Comment: The color simply stands for another variable that is the ANSII(I think thats the acronym) code for color. but regardless, its the If statement that is the problem, not the actual assigning.

Comment: Notice the capital C color, it is a data type that you need to import form java.awt.Color, What you are assigning isn't a string as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: but does that even help though? I dont have any graphics, I just want to change how text looks in the console, and from all I saw, the "Color" datatype didnt seem to do that.

Comment: It definetely will, look at the next answer. If you don't use this you will have to verify your string for what color it is with ifs and elses. If you use color it will store the actual color that you can use directly.

Comment: I appreciate it. Is there a way you could link a resource for this to me, or show me fully how I would implement this in my code?

Comment: I updated my answer as you requested

Comment: I still dont see how this helps though as its the actual implementation of the "If/else" that i need. I already know how to do the color, but with what i have, an "if/else" doesnt compile, sorry. But at least i learned more about the Colors lol.

Comment: Ok, so what you need to do is this (you may need to look tutorials for this):
-Have a Card class (you already do)
-Set the values this class will need (done agin with string suit... and int value...)
-Implement a constructor, this is a "method" that will generate the values for the card
-Create a new object of this card class using your constructor and assign it to a name ( in the main)
-You may now use this object with the name as you see fit

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it was this code that wasn't working:

```java
**if(suit.equals("Spades") || suit.equals("Clubs")){
    String cardColor = Colors.WHITE;
} else {
    String cardColor = Colors.RED;
}**
```

This code is creating a variable called `color` inside each block, but then the variable is discarded without anything being done with it. If your program compiles, even though you have the code:

```java
String cardDisplay = value + ", "+ cardColor + suit + Colors.RESET;
```

Then it means the variable called `cardColor` that that line is accessing is not the variable you assigned a color to conditionally in the code with the if statement. The solution to the problem you're encountering right now is to identify what variable called `cardColor` is being accessed on the line with `String cardDisplay =` and ensure that that variable is the one being modified depending on the suit in your if statement blocks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to think more object-oriented about it:

First create some enums, I would suggest a Suit and FaceValue enum:

```
public enum Suit {
SPADE(Color.BLACK, "Spades"),
CLUB(Color.BLACK, "Clubs"),
HEART(Color.RED, "Hearts"),
DIAMOND(Color.RED, "Diamonds");

private Color color;
private String displayValue;

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

private Suit(Color color, String displayValue) {
    this.color = color;
    this.displayValue = displayValue;
}

public String toString() {
    return displayValue;
}
}

public enum FaceValue {
TWO("2"),
THREE("3"),
FOUR("4"),
FIVE("5"),
SIX("6"),
SEVEN("7"),
EIGHT("8"),
NINE("9"),
TEN("10"),
JACK("J"),
QUEEN("Q"),
KING("K"),
ACE("A");

private String displayValue;

private FaceValue(String displayValue) {
    this.displayValue = displayValue;
}

public String toString() {
    return displayValue;
}
}
```

Then a card class:

```
public class Card {
private Suit suit;
private FaceValue value;

public Card(Suit suit, FaceValue value) {
    this.suit = suit;
    this.value = value;
}

public Suit getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public FaceValue getValue() {
    return value;
}

public String toString() {
    return value + " of " + suit; 
}
}
```

Then you can create a deck class with basic functionality.

```
public class Deck {
private List<Card> cards = new LinkedList<Card>();

public Deck() {
    init();
    shuffle();
}

public void init() {
    cards.clear();
    for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
        for (FaceValue faceValue : FaceValue.values()) {
            cards.add(new Card(suit, faceValue));
        }
    }
}

public void shuffle() {
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
}

public Card drawCard() {
    return cards.remove(0);
}

public boolean hasCards() {
    return !cards.isEmpty();
}
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Deck deck = new Deck();
    while (deck.hasCards()) {
        System.out.println(deck.drawCard());
    }
}
}
```

From there you can create games and such.  A player could have a Hand of Cards.  Then it's all just a matter of adding rules.

Comment: This seems way beyond my scope at the moment, i have never even heard of Enums before. i think for the project requirements, this goes so far beyond that it doesnt actually meet them, but I do appreciate it. Maybe if I knew how to work better with Enums but even still.

Comment: That solution seems to be super overpowered. OP didn't ask for a super complete solution to the whole task, but why his "class" is not working, probably not even compiling.

Comment: enums are basically pre-defined values that aren't meant to do much; think of it as a limited class.  For something like cards, it's the ideal solution: the values are known and they aren't numerous.   But you don't have to use enums. You could create a class to do the same thing, it's just making it more difficult.

Comment: Just to add:  This may not solve your immediately problem, but my goal was to get you to think about a problem by breaking it into objects/classes.  One of the biggest hurdles for new developers is not form bad habits.  Trying to do everything in a single class and primitives will cause you trouble down the road.

Comment: @Ryan I appreciate it a lot but im only in a freshman High School class, and Im already extremely advanced for my class, so I kinda dont have a choice in terms of what I use/habits i build. But I do appreciate the sentiment, and ill do my best to think about that in the future.